# How to query ActiveRecord with having and group

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, group-by, having

I have a simple Appointment model storing a start_time and user_id. I'd like to get all appointments starting in the next 7 days in ascending order and grouped by day. Ideally the result will be a hash or a multidimensional array such as

```
{
  '30 March' => 
     [appt1,appt12, appt3],
  '31 March' =>
     [appt5,appt2, appt7,appt8],
  '1 April' => 
     [appt10,appt11,appt9, appt6,appt4],
  '2 April' =>
     [appt15,appt21]
}
```

The query below gets the desired results but not in the format I want.

```
Appointment.order(start_time: :asc).where("start_time <= ?", 7.days.from_now.end_of_day)
```

Is there a way to structure the query or do I need to format the result separately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is with `group_by`

```
appointments = Appointment.order(start_time: :asc).
  where("start_time <= ?", 7.days.from_now.end_of_day).
  group_by { |a| a.start_time.to_date }
```

Comment: That's what I've ended up doing, I was just wondering if this could be done as part of the sql query